# Generator class not working as expected with concurrency

Tags: python, loops, pytorch, multiprocessing, generator

I'm doing a project to create an [Image Semantic Search](https://github.com/EduardoPach/Semantic-Image-Search) and one of the steps is pre-computing the images embeddings to do that I'm using an `ImageBatchGenerator` class that should take a list of URLs and a batch size so I can later loop and compute the embeddings. I also wanted to add multiprocessing so this process goes faster therefore I've used Python's `concurrent.futures`

So far this is my implementation:

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from typing import Union
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

from PIL import Image

def fetch_image(url: str) -> tuple[str, Image.Image]:
    """Fetch image from url

    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str
        url of the image

    Returns
    -------
    tuple[str, Image.Image]
        tuple (url, image) where image is PIL image object and url is the url of the image
    """
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return url, Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print(f"HTTP Error: {errh}")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print(f"Error Connecting: {errc}")
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print(f"Timeout Error: {errt}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print(f"Something Else: {err}")
    return None

class ImageBatchGenerator:
    """
    A generator class that get's as arguments a list of URLs and batch size and generates batches of PIL images
    that are obtained through GET requests to the URLs.

    Parameters
    ----------
    urls : list[str]
        List of URLs to fetch images from
    batch_size : int
        The size of the batches to be generated
    """
    def __init__(self, urls: list[str], batch_size: int=32) -> None:
        self.urls = urls
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return (len(self.urls) + self.batch_size - 1) // self.batch_size

    def __iter__(self) -> ImageBatchGenerator:
        self.futures = [self.executor.submit(fetch_image, url) for url in self.urls]
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> dict[str, Union[str, Image.Image]]:
        images = []
        urls = []
        for future in as_completed(self.futures):
            url, image = future.result()
            if image is not None:
                images.append(image)
                urls.append(url)
            if len(images) == self.batch_size:
                break
        if len(images) == 0:
            self.executor.shutdown()
            raise StopIteration
        return {"images": images, "urls": urls}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting a lot of repetition for URLs (i.e. loading the same image more than once), though the list contains only unique URLs.

To test it I used this:

```py
data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EduardoPach/Semantic-Image-Search/main/data.csv")
urls = data["path"].tolist()
batch_generator = utils.ImageBatchGenerator(urls)
counter = {}
for idx, batch_dict in enumerate(batch_generator):
    images, urls = batch_dict.values()
    print(f"Doing Batch {idx+1}")
    for url in urls:
        if url in counter:
            print(f"\t found url ({url}) again")
            counter[url] += 1
        else:
            counter[url] = 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as a Future becomes "completed" you are not removing it from `self.futures`. Each time `__iter__` is called the Future instances are reiterated from the start of the collection and so the first completed Future will always be the one returned.

The simplest fix is to make `self.futures` a set so that removal of a completed Future is efficient:

```py
    ...
    def __iter__(self) -> ImageBatchGenerator:
        # Use a set:
        self.futures = {self.executor.submit(fetch_image, url) for url in self.urls}
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> dict[str, Union[str, Image.Image]]:
        images = []
        urls = []
        for future in as_completed(self.futures):
            # Remove completed future:
            self.futures.remove(future)
            url, image = future.result()
            ... # etc.
```

**Another Solution**

You iterate the `as_completed` iterator once in the following way:

```py
    def __iter__(self) -> ImageBatchGenerator:
        self.futures = [self.executor.submit(fetch_image, url) for url in self.urls]
        # Create the iterator once here:
        self.as_completed = as_completed(self.futures)
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> dict[str, Union[str, Image.Image]]:
        images = []
        urls = []
        try:
            while True:
                future = next(self.as_completed)
                url, image = future.result()
                if image is not None:
                    images.append(image)
                    urls.append(url)
                if len(images) == self.batch_size:
                    return {"images": images, "urls": urls}
        except StopIteration:
            self.executor.shutdown()
            if len(images) == 0:
                raise
            return {"images": images, "urls": urls}
```

Comment: Although the first solution required the fewest code changes, I would recommend the second solution as being "best."